# Remove <style> on production webpack build - vuejs

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I would like to ask how can I put all of this `<style>` tags in my html inside a css file using webpack config. The content of the `<style>` are from the node_modules from the `vue-strap` library that I install via npm. I checked the .vue of the library and there are css styles inside. How can I separate it when I do the productioin build.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `ExtractTextPlugin` for webpack to extract all CSS into a seperate `.css` file that you then have to inlcude in the index.html page.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/

Comment: I already did this, but in only combine all of my css files inside my development folder. but not inside the node_modules folder for example I have .vue component inside node_modules from the 3rd party library. the css there is not included.